After deploying my spl_token_2022.so successfully, i do not know how to initialize the metadata and create the mint account. I used SPL git repository
I cloned the SPL git repository and followed all the instructions and I have been able to deploy my spl_token_2022 file successfully and I can see it in both localhost and devnet.
The next phase should be to get the mint address and add the metadata like name, symbol and uri. I cannot seem to get this. I am using this: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/js/examples and I want to run the metadata.ts
Please how do I interact with my program and initialize it to get the mint address and also add metadata. Here is my script "metadata": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm examples/metadata.ts",
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/examples/metadata.ts
Executing task: pnpm run metadata
> @solana/spl-token@0.4.4 metadata /home/devgraves/solana-program-library/token/js
> node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm examples/metadata.ts

(node:24027) ExperimentalWarning: `--experimental-loader` may be removed in the future; instead use `register()`:
--import 'data:text/javascript,import { register } from "node:module"; import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url"; register("ts-node/esm", pathToFileURL("./"));'
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

node:internal/modules/run_main:129
    triggerUncaughtException(
    ^
[Object: null prototype] {
  [Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)]: [Function: [nodejs.util.inspect.custom]]
}

Node.js v20.14.0
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.


I just tested this out, and it seems to work with a simple setup. Try the following:
npm i @solana/spl-token
npm i @solana/web3.js@1.91
npm i @solana/spl-token-metadata

Rename the file to js:
mv examples/metadata.ts examples/metadata.js

Remove the TokenMetadata import and type usage.
Then just run it:
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node examples/metadata.js

